# Transfer Project Standards Revit

Tags: revit-api, revit, revit-2015

I would like to transfer project standards through revit API. I am able to copy all the elements except shared parameters. Please let me know how can I copy the shared parameters while doing transfer project standards.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that Transfer Project Standards is currently not accessible through the Revit API. In some cases, you can work around that limitation using the copy and paste API. Here are some in-depth discussions of the topic:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/09/transfer-project-standards.html

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/12/restoring-a-missing-project-information-element.html

http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/transfer-project-standards-revit-api/td-p/6828310

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for your quick response. CopyElements worked for me. It copied all the builtin parameters from source wallType to target walltype except the shared parameter. I was able to write an API which would copy all the shared parameters to the target wallType. 
 
Thanks so much for your help!