How to check the View Templets item in the UI of TransferProjectStandards via user32.dll
in Revit i am trying to select the checkbox next to 'View Templates' in a ListBox of the TransferProjectStandards Dialog. I was able to implement the 'Check None' functionality, but I couldn't figure out how to interact with the individual items in the ListBox. I'll provide my code for better clarification. I appreciate any suggestions you may have.
Thank you
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace RunTransfer
{
    public class ListBoxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static List<ListBoxItem> listBoxItems = new List<ListBoxItem>();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

        private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        const int MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 512;
        const uint BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
        const uint LB_GETCOUNT = 0x018B;
        const uint LB_GETTEXT = 0x0189;
        const uint BM_SETCHECK = 0x00F1;
        const uint BST_CHECKED = 0x0001;
        const uint LB_SETCURSEL = 0x0186;

        static IntPtr FindTransferProjectStandardsWindow()
        {
            return FindWindow(null, "Transfer Project Standards");
        }

        static void EnumerateChildWindows(IntPtr parentHandle, EnumWindowsProc callback)
        {
            EnumChildWindows(parentHandle, callback, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            StringBuilder windowText = new StringBuilder(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
            StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);

            GetWindowText(hWnd, windowText, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
            GetClassName(hWnd, className, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);

            Console.WriteLine($"Window Title: {windowText}, Class: {className}");

            // Click "Check &None" button
            if (windowText.ToString() == "Check &None")
            {
                SendMessage(hWnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
                return true; // Continue enumeration
            }

            // Handle ListBox items
            if (className.ToString().Contains("ListBox"))
            {
                int itemCount = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0); // LB_GETCOUNT

                for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
                {
                    StringBuilder itemText = new StringBuilder(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
                    SendMessage(hWnd, LB_GETTEXT, i, itemText);

                    ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem
                    {
                        Text = itemText.ToString(),
                        Index = i
                    };

                    listBoxItems.Add(item);

                    Console.WriteLine($"  ListBox Item {i + 1}: Text: {item.Text}");

                    if (item.Text == "View Templates")
                    {
                        // Select the "View Templates" item
                        SendMessage(hWnd, LB_SETCURSEL, i, 0);
                        Console.WriteLine("     Selected the 'View Templates' item");

                        // Locate and check the checkbox associated with "View Templates"
                        IntPtr checkboxHandle = FindCheckboxHandle(hWnd);
                        if (checkboxHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            SendMessage(checkboxHandle, BM_SETCHECK, (int)BST_CHECKED, 0);
                            Console.WriteLine("     Checked the 'View Templates' item");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("     Could not find the checkbox handle for 'View Templates'");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return true; 
        }

        static IntPtr FindCheckboxHandle(IntPtr listBoxHandle)
        {
            IntPtr checkboxHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

            // Enumerate child windows of the parent to find the checkbox
            EnumChildWindows(listBoxHandle, (childHwnd, lParam) =>
            {
                StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
                GetClassName(childHwnd, className, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);

                StringBuilder windowText = new StringBuilder(MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
                GetWindowText(childHwnd, windowText, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);

                Console.WriteLine($"Child Window Title: {windowText}, Class: {className}");

                // Check for checkbox
                if (className.ToString().Contains("Button"))
                {
                    checkboxHandle = childHwnd;
                    return false; 
                }
                return true; 
            }, IntPtr.Zero);

            return checkboxHandle;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run();
        }

        static void Run()
        {
            IntPtr transferWindow = FindTransferProjectStandardsWindow();

            if (transferWindow != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Transfer Project Standards window found.");
                EnumerateChildWindows(transferWindow, EnumWindow);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Transfer Project Standards window not found.");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}


get into the selection of the items in the ListBox of the TransferProjectStandards in Revit

What is your end goal here? Could this be solved using Revit's API instead?

This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837667/transfer-project-standards-revit
